# Java: Using BufferedReader and PrintWriter in Conjunction Causes Issues

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to learn about Java's io package through experimentation and from the book "Java2: the Complete Reference (5th ed.)". Below, I have tried to make a very simple program to take some input using a BufferedReader instance and deliver some simple console output with PrintWriter instances.

```
package io;

import java.io.*;

public class UsingPrinterWriter {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        Profile hypro = Profile.promptedProfile();
        output.print(hypro);
        output.close();
        return;
    }
}

class Profile {
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private int age;

    Profile() {}

    Profile(String first_name, String last_name, int age) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    void setFirstName(String fn) {
        this.first_name = fn;
        return;
    }

    void setLastName(String ln) {
        this.last_name = ln;
        return;
    }

    void setAge(int a) {
        this.age = a;
        return;
    }

    static Profile promptedProfile() {
        Profile new_profile = new Profile();

        // create the writer and reader
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            // prompt for first name
            output.print("Enter your first name: ");
            new_profile.setFirstName(input.readLine());

            // prompt for last name
            output.print("Enter your last name: ");
            new_profile.setLastName(input.readLine());

            // prompt for age
            output.print("Enter your age: ");
            while(true) {
                try {
                    new_profile.setAge(Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()));
                    if(new_profile.age > 0 && new_profile.age < 110) {
                        break;
                    }
                    throw new NumberFormatException("Out of bounds.");
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    output.print("Invalid response, try again: ");
                }
            }
            input.close();          
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            output.println(ioe);
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }

        return new_profile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Profile:\n  Name: %s %s\n  Age: %d\n", this.first_name, this.last_name, this.age);
    }
}
```

**Issue 1**:
when I run this (Using the Eclipse IDE) the output I get is a blank terminal, where, once I enter a string, another string, and a valid integer, all one after the other in newlines, (then)the prompt lines where I do output.print(...) get printed. Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
first
last
20
Enter your first name: Enter your last name: Enter your age:
```

**Issue 2**:
The line: `output.print(hypro);` won't get printed. Anything after the line `Profile hypro = Profile.promptedProfile();`.

So I'd like to ask:

1. what's going on here (the conceptual knowledge about these io classes that I seem to be missing) ?
2. what can I do to resolve these issues?

In advance, thank you.

P.S. I'm already aware of the java.util.Scanner class but I want to solve this issue without using it. Also, I'm open to suggestions about any better programming practices that I should have implemented here.

Comment: You seem to be creating multiple `output`s, when you need zero since there's already `System.out` that you should be using. It's hard to follow the code when it's filled with unnecessary things. Basically your problem probably stems from creating those wrappers and they all share the `System.in` and `out` that you should be using. You can create a `BufferedReader` for reading input, but you don't need to do anything for output. Only create **one** and share that.

Comment: @Kayaman, in the book, Herbert Schildt says: "There is nothing wrong with using System.out to write simple text output to the console when you are learning Java or debugging your programs. However using a PrintWriter will make your real-world applications easier to internationalize. " (since it's a character stream and not a byte stream). This is why I'm insisting on using the seemingly unnecessary PrintWriter instances.
I have used BufferedReader  before in conjunction with System.out directly and have not faced issues. But That's not what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Well, real world applications don't really print to the console anymore, so the book's age is showing. Still, I'm sure the book doesn't say "create a new `PrintWriter` everywhere". You can wrap `in` and `out`, but if you do, do it once. The book might be a bad fit for you too, it seems to be a "quick reference".

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, the book mentioned that " real world applications don't really print to the console anymore" and you're right, it's more of a quick reference I guess. Anyhow I realized my mistake: When we _chain_ input or output streams (i.e. wrap them around each other) closing the outer stream will automatically close the inner streams as well. I guess that's what I needed to know (for issue 2 anyhow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a few basics:

First of all *what does flushing of a stream means?*, well, it simply means that when you flush a buffered stream, all the data from it is cleared off and sent to the target destination. In your code, flushing output would make sure that all the data in it is sent to the console (System.out) for printing.

Secondly the stream System.out is a **STATIC** stream, that is you get only one copy of that, and on closing it you can not use it again for printing things.

**Issue 1**:Now although you have enabled autoflushing (`PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); // the second argument is true`), the autoflush is called only when \r\n (Carriage return line feed, CRLF) or a \n is encountered, and since your output statements miss those characters, none of the prompts get printed as the stream is not flushed at the correct times. The data keeps on  appending to the stream until the end of the program when the autoflush finally runs for the first and the last time and, as a result, all the statements are printed in a line when the program terminates.

**To fix**: As explained in a previous answer, you can either use `println()` instead of `print()` or you can add the missing characters to the `print()` call like:

`output.print(new_profile.getName() + "\r\n")`

Or you can manually call flush() after each print() call (edit suggested by @EJP) if you'd like to get the outputs in the same line

**Issue 2**: As I just said, the System.out stream is a static one and since you close the stream when you call `promptedProfile()`, you can not use it again in your UsePrinterWriter class' main method. You can try printing something else before the function call like this:

`output.println("foo bar");    //print something here
 Profile hypro = Profile.promptedProfile();`

You will see that `foo bar` is printed on the console.

**To fix**: As in for fixing this issue, I'd say print everything in a single function and print everything before calling close() on a writer object that uses System.out, or you can simply use `System.out.println();` to avoid all this altogether ;)

Comment: OP may not want line-terminated output for his prompts. There is another solution.

Comment: @EJP Well, all that I had in mind while writing the answer was the flush() call, (don't know how I forgot that,) so I don't know if there is another solution that you were talking about, would be glad if you could tell us about it

And thank you for pointing it out man! 

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter` is buffered, and doesn't flush itself until either:

1. You call `flush()`, or
2. You constructed it with `true` for the `autoflush` argument *and* you printed a line terminator, either by calling `println()`, or by having `\n` or `\r\n` in the data passed to `print()` or `write()`.

You aren't doing any of these things. If you want line-terminated output to appear immediately after `print()`, you need to flush.

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't use return statement for setters.
2. You can open only one PrintWriter and pass that to your promptedProfile() method
3. Use println(String str) method of PrintWriter to print to console
4. Close the PrintWriter once everything is done.
5. Use proper java variable convention

### Try the below code and understand yourself.

```
import java.io.*;

public class UsingPrinterWriter {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        Profile hypro = Profile.promptedProfile(output);
        output.print("\n");
        output.flush();
        output.println(hypro);
        output.close();
    }
}

class Profile {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;

Profile() {
}

Profile(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}

void setFirstName(String fn) {
    this.firstName = fn;

}

void setLastName(String ln) {
    this.firstName = ln;
}

void setAge(int a) {
    this.age = a;
}

static Profile promptedProfile(PrintWriter output) {
    Profile newProfile = new Profile();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
        // prompt for first name
        output.println("Enter your first name: ");
        output.flush();
        newProfile.setFirstName(input.readLine());

        // prompt for last name
        output.println("Enter your last name: ");
        output.flush();
        newProfile.setLastName(input.readLine());

        // prompt for age
        output.println("Enter your age: ");
        output.flush();
        while (true) {
            try {
                newProfile.setAge(Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()));
                if (newProfile.age > 0 && newProfile.age < 110) {
                    break;
                }
                throw new NumberFormatException("Out of bounds.");
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                output.println("Invalid response, try again: ");
            }
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        output.println(ioe);
    }

    return newProfile;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Profile:\n  Name: %s %s\n  Age: %d\n", this.firstName, this.lastName, this.age);
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually explained anything here, and the OP did ask for 'conceptual knowledge': and several of your recommendations are off. Closing the `PrintWriter` would also close `System.out`, which is undesirable in general; and the OP may not want line-terminated output for his prompts.

Comment: Your edits are all futile. All they do is (1) add extra line terminators and (2) call `flush()` when it *isn't* needed. And there is still no explanation here.